# Automapper MapsTo Attribute does not work on referenced classes

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong here. I've been using Automapper + Automapper.Attributes (https://github.com/schneidenbach/AutoMapper.Attributes) in a solution and recently I've had to split my API project out into a "core" library and the original API. Automapper is not able to create a map when the class files are move outside of the API project. I have setup a demo project with the following structure to confirm this issue: (Available here: https://github.com/greghesom/AutoMapper_Example)

- Solution

  - API (Customer and Person Class)
  - API.Core (Pet and Dog classes)

---

- The API project references API.Core
- The Pet class maps to the Dog class
- The Person class maps to the Customer Class

---

**API.Core - Dog Class**

```
namespace API.Core
{
    public class Dog
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**API.Core - Pet Class**

```
namespace API.Core
{
    [MapsTo(typeof(Dog))]
    public class Pet
    {
        [MapsToProperty(typeof(Dog), "Name")] //Edit: Fixed this typo
        public string PetName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**API - Person Class**

```
namespace API.Models
{
    [MapsTo(typeof(Customer))]
    public class Person
    {
        [MapsToProperty(typeof(Customer), "FirstName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**API - Customer Class**

```
namespace API.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**API - Startup**

```
   AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
                typeof(API.WebApiConfig).Assembly.MapTypes(cfg);  
            });
```

**API - Controller**

```
var person = new Person { Name = "John" };
var customer = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Customer>(person);//This Works

var dog = new Dog { Name = "Lucky" };
var pet = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Pet>(dog);//This throws exception
```

**EXCEPTION:**

> An error has occurred.
>   Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
>   ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>   ============================= AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration.
>   Dog -> Pet (Destination member list) API.Core.Dog ->
>   API.Core.Pet (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties: PetName
>   AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Dog , Pet , ResolutionContext )    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object , ResolutionContext )    at
>   API.Controllers.ValuesController.Get() in
>   c:\users\greg\Source\Repos\AutoMapperTest\API\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line
>   26    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()

Comment: MapsToProperty on PetName of Pet class is declared incorrectly. It should be typeof(Dog) instead of typeof(Pet).

Comment: Th GITHub project has test cases with that particular method, I suggest comparing & running those tests and checking those samples and your code.

Comment: @user1672994 add it as an answer ;-)

Comment: Apologies for the MapsToProperty Typo. I have updated the example project and the issue still exists

Comment: Does `var customer = new Customer{ Name = "John" };
var person = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Person>(customer);` mapping work for you? Since you have defined Map for Person to Course mapping that's in your question it worked. But in case of Dog, you have defined the mapping for `Pet` to `Dog` but you are trying to map `dog` object to `pet` object (and the mapping does not exist.)

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?  I came across [this article](https://fluxmatix.com/en/blog/how-to-setup-automapper-asp-net-core) and tried it and this seemed to work, but simply using `services.AddAutoMapper()` did not, not sure if what is suggested in the article is the correct approach or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue (AutoMapper 7.0.0).  The key to the problem is in the error message: "AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration".  From 6.2.0 onwards AutoMapper tries to create mappings itself for types that aren't explicitly mapped, ie: in a lot of cases it's no longer needed to create a mapping.

However, it seems that it's using the mappings it creates itself instead of your defined mappings, even for the types you explicitly defined them for.  At least, that's what I ran into.

A quick way to check this: downgrade to version 6.1.1, and see if the problem still occurs.  In my case, the downgrade solved the issue.

I do have a feeling there must be a better way to fix this (or maybe it's even a bug...), but I don't know how yet.  In case I find it, I'll post back here. Just figured I'd thrown this out here already in case you need a quick fix :)

Comment: AM creates a map for you only when no existing map applies.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu My constructor on my profile isn't even getting called at any time from initialization to the point I call Map on my entities. It seems like AutoMapper is ignoring my profile completely, but when I inspect the configuration object, I see my profile registered. I'm about to toss AutoMapper out the window. Something is truly screwed up in 7.x

Comment: You're just missing smth. Otherwise you'd be able make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: One thing to try is to set CreateMissingTypeMaps to false. That makes things easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

MapsToProperty on PetName of Pet class is declared incorrectly. It should be typeof(Dog) instead of typeof(Pet).

```
    [MapsTo(typeof(Dog))]
    public class Pet
    {
        [MapsToProperty(typeof(Dog), "Name")]
        public string PetName { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit

Since you have defined the Mapping for `Person` to `Customer` mapping that's in your question it worked. But in case of `Dog`, you have defined the mapping for `Pet` to `Dog` but you are trying to map `dog` object to `pet` object (but the mapping does not exist).

If you are required two way mapping, then would suggest you to define the mapping using `MapsToAndFromProperty`.

Check [this](https://github.com/schneidenbach/AutoMapper.Attributes#two-way-mapping) link for further details.

Comment: This was a typo, I have corrected it and the issue still exists.